# How do you write a database-triggered firebase function to an external api?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

How do you write a post request to an external API, using a firebase database function trigger? (I already paid for the flame plan that lets you make calls to external apis)

For example, you write {name} to firebase database. When written to firebase database, the function is triggered and post-request is made to the external api endpoint www.externalendpoint.com?

```
exports.functionName=functions.database.ref('path/to/data/').onWrite(event=>{
//post request using the event.data.val()
})
```

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Simply require axios (or fetch) and return a promise:

```
exports.functionName=functions.database.ref('path/to/data/').onWrite(event=>{
   const data = event.data.val()
   return axios.post('https://my-api.com/endpoint', { data })
})
```

Make sure you **return** the promise so that the function execution ends once it is resolved otherwise you might get 408 request timed out and it will pump up your costs

Answer (score 0):

Use the request library. You can install it using npm, but it should come in the set of libraries you get when you set up Firebase Functions with your project. Here's the documentation just in case:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

To use the request library, use require at the beginning of your code:

```
var request = require('request');
```

Compose your headers in a dictionary, such as:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: www.externalendpoint.com,
    body: {
        'data': event.data.val()
    },
    headers: {
        'app_id': [YOUR_ID],
        'app_key': [YOUR_KEY]
    },
        json: true
}
```

Then you can send it like this:

```
request(options)
.then(function(repos) {

    // HANDLE RESPONSE HERE

})
.catch(function(err) {
    // HANDLE ERROR HERE
})
```

Hope this helps!